# Multiple values in multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Hello i'm working on some project and i have 6 dropdowns and every has it values

Example in first dropdown i have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dt1" name="dt1" value="1">20 kW<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="dt2" name="dt2" value="2">40 kW <br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="dt3" name="dt3" value="3">60 kW <br>
```

And in Other i have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="stv1" name="stv1" value="6">500 L<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="stv2" name="stv2" value="7">1000 L<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="stv3" name="stv3" value="8">"2000 L<br>
```

But now i have many questions first how can i make drop down with only one selection? 
second question is how can i give result when someone choose from drop down one value 1 and from drop down 2 value 8 how can i make value1+value8=link?

Till now i have used

```
if (containsOnly(values, ['1', '8'])) {
        alert('something');
    }
```

but now i dont need alert, i need link so if someone can help me or do something on JS Fiddle that would be great

my latest work on this topic was this http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/bUdra/5/ but now its not just choice a b or c, it must be choice a drop down with 3 or 4 choices and without alert.. If someone could help me it would be great

Comment: Sidenote: Those are not dropdown `<select>...</select>` codes; what you have (posted) are checkboxes. Two different animals altogether. ;-)

Comment: Yeah i now notice.. i didnt copy the full code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this code you can get both values in the same file or in an other file just edit it to what you need:

```
<?php
    if($_POST) {
    $dd1 = $_POST['dropdown1'];
    $dd2 = $_POST['dropdown2'];

header('Location: file.php?dd1='.$dd1.'&dd2='.$dd2);
exit();
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="dropdown1">
        <option value="20">20 kW</option> 
        <option value="40">40 kW</option> 
        <option value="60">60 kW</option>
    </select>

    <select name="dropdown2">
        <option value="500">500 L</option> 
        <option value="1000">1000 L</option> 
        <option value="2000">2000 L</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

file.php could then be something like:

```
<?php
$dd1 = strip_tags($_GET['dd1']);
$dd2 = strip_tags($_GET['dd2']);

echo $dd1; //should give you the value from dropdown1
echo $dd2; //should give yout the value from dropdown2
?>

<!-- the php variables can also be used in javascript -->
<!-- don't know for sure if this is the correct way to use php in javascript but atleast should be something like this -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown1 = <?php $dd1; ?>;
var dropdown2 = <?php $dd2; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: How is the `calculate()` function supposed to be called? It's not in the OP's jsfiddle. Your answer is not fully functional.

Comment: Thanks for noticing I tried something in javascript but at the end changed it to php and forgot to take that out. changed it now

Comment: This is something to begin with.. but, how can i call them to make some action? example if dd1 value="20" is selected and dd2 value "1000" is selected then go to... how can i do that? that is only thing that i need right now..

Comment: header('Location: file.php?dd1='.$dd1.'&dd2='.$dd2); this line points you to a file where you start to calculate by a $_GET like $dd1 = $_GET['dd1'] you get the falue from the url

Comment: I gave you solved for your anwser up but can you help me a litlle bit more? i didn't get your response.. can you give me example how can i submit if selected values 40 and value 500 to a http://www.mysite.com/test.php ? I hope you understand me.. before i used if (containsOnly(values, ['1', '8'])) {
        alert('http://www.mysite.com/test.php');
    }
But that was for checkboxes and didnt open link  instead it was given alert.. i hope you understand..